# Button auto-clicks once on load, then can't be clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, click

I'm trying to have a button click cause a variable to increment by one, then update a page counter showing the variable. For some reason, upon page load, the button will apparently click once, and any actual clicks do nothing.

I've tried `$("#click").click(click(1));` and putting `onClick="click(1)"` on the actual HTML of the button, but both seem to output the same result.

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="column_middle"> 
    <div style="font-size:115%;display:inline;">Money: <span id="money">0</span></div>

    <button id="click" class="mainbutton" style="margin:10px;margin-right:5px;" title="">Click</button>
```

And the relevant javascript:

```
// Activated on DOM load
function onLoad( jQuery ) {
    // Set up button functions
    $("#click").click(click(1));
}

function click(amount) { // Player clicking
    money += amount; // Add the amount of clicks to the total money

    html_money.text(money); // Update page money value

    console.log("Clicked "+amount+" times.");
}

// Variable declaration
var money = 0; // Total money
var stock = 0; // Total stock
    var html_money = $("#money"); // Money variable on the actual page
    var html_stock = $("#stock"); // Stock variable on the actual page
```

Comment: Check the updated code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least this line will not work: `$("#click").click(click(1));` because on the click event, you will "execute" the returned value of the click function (void), not the function itself.

Try this:

```
<div class="column_middle">
    <div style="font-size:115%;display:inline;">Money: <span id="money">0</span></div>
    <button id="incrementButton" class="mainbutton" style="margin:10px;margin-right:5px;" title="">Click</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var increment = function (amount) {
    $('#money').text(
      parseInt($('#money').text(), 10) + amount
    );
  }  

  $('#incrementButton').click(function () {
    increment(1);
  });

  increment(1);

});
```

I also created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cP6Lq/

Answer (score 0):

change your code to:

```
function incrementMoney(amount) { // Player clicking
    $("#money").html( parseInt($("#money").html()) + amount);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#click").click(function(){
        incrementMoney(1));
    });
}
```

*it is very important to avoid using qualified names specially if you have element ids named just like functions..*

Comment: Didn't work - same result. Also, I'm using jQuery 2.0.3 which doesn't support IE8 and below, so I'm not supporting old IE anyways.

Comment: Check the updated code above and make sure you call the onLoad method,